# Is it possible to load an URL using Text View in Android?

Tags: android

I am interested to load an URL using Text View in Android.
Do you know if Android:imeOptions attribute can be used in order to load an URL on the target? I am interested to be able to see if the URL was sucessfuly loaded and Android:imeOptions is the only thing related text view that I was able to find.
If you have any other suggestions please share.
I am interested in any kind of documentation that may help me in order to start my activities.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: BTW-  imeOptions has nothing to do with the network.  It tells the keyboard some information about the type of text that goes in an EditView, so the keyboard can customize itself (show the number keyboard, add .com keys, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, why would you want to do that?  But no, TextView has no internet ability.  Nor should it-  talk about feature bloat.  If you want to do that, you need to fetch it separately and then set the text.  You can then turn that into a custom view that does it automatically if you really need to.

Comment: The idea is that I have to perform some web browsing activities and I can not use Web View as an interface due to Google access restrictions. Someone suggested me Text View, but as far as I understand from your comments it is not a very good choice. Do you have any other suggestions of interfaces/applications that I can use for web browsing / URLs loading activities?